# What resources have the most accurate market research for salaries?

Tags: salary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)

I have been writing software for 15 years. I've run the gamut of creating large scale software applications from scratch, to maintenance, support, and leading a team of developers. My technology skill set is good with .NET, Web Services, etc.

I'm going through a recruiter and was extended a job offer where the I.T. Director told me that I wasn't worth the $85K that I was asking. Through their market research, they said, they would only offer $73K which, considering my current benefits, would be less than what I'm making now. They made the promise: we'll take care of you and you'll grow here.

I spoke with my CEO about how they determine salaries and they will be reviewing them this year using "current market research" but their past market research wasn't very good.

My recruiter is stating that they feel that they can get get me interviewed in the range of $80-$85K but they feel it would be hard to get me in at the $85K range.

I have a friend that works locally for a nationally known Fortune 500 company and he pulled salary statistics for his organization and their range goes anywhere from $70K to $100K for my skills.

I've been to Salary.com and indeed.com and they say, assuming I'm matching skills appropriately, that $85K is the lower 10% for my skills.

Where can I find accurate "market research"?

Comment: I too would like to know where HR departments (and recruitment agencies, for that matter) pull their figures out of...

Comment: @Oded - there is a reason their numbers have a stink that never seems to go away...

Comment: Something to keep in mind with those salary sites is they often include benefits in the final dollar amount they show you, so the salary offered by companies is most likely lower than what those sites show depending on what sort of benefits are offered.