# When facing a low salary offer, should I ask for more than my desired salary in order to "negotiate" down to my desired salary?

Tags: salary, negotiation

I have received a salary offer from a company that I am very interested in working for.
However the salary is only just over half my expected salary for my education level, though I am still interested in working for them.

I have direct experience and very relevant knowledge relating to the project I would be initially working, but otherwise not a huge amount of experience overall.

It is initially project work, with a six months contract

I am very un-used to bargaining in regards to payment for work and wonder now that I see the employers salary offering range should I counter offer with something above my reduced expectation or equal to it? For example, if my target is 30k should I counter with 30k or 35k?

Comment: See also [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for) for a lot of tips

Comment: @enderland I'm not positive that it is a duplicate of that question, as it doesn't seem to contain the answer to this question. I think Toby is asking specifically about if he should go in with his initial offer, or go in with a higher offer and "negotiate" down to his initial offer. There may be a duplicate somewhere on this site about that, but I don't think it's the question you linked

Comment: @Rachel - The linked question covers the same topic.  This question can not be answered with out getting into many specifics that would make the question too localized.  The general how can i effectively negotiate is the best place to direct the OP.

Comment: @Chad In addition to the linked question not asking about the same scenario, it doesn't actually contain an answer addressing this specific part of the negotiation process (If you should ask for your desired salary when facing a low offer, or a higher salary to "negotiate" down to your desired salary). Personally I'm very interested in the answer myself, and don't see it anywhere in the linked question. I think this would be a good question to have answered separately on the site.

Comment: Are you negotiating directly, or through some recruiter?

Comment: Negotiating directly and already have a good working relationship with the employer.

Comment: Indeed the linked Q's are helpful but are more pointed at what amount to decide to ask for, rather than how to ask for it so that you reach the intended target. I understand there are a lot of salary negotiation Q's already and I did read quite a lot before posting  but still feel as outlined on the direction of this Q

Comment: I'm no expert at salary negotiation, however my best advice would just be to stay honest with them. State that the offer is lower than what you wanted, but you are still interested in the job, and that you'd be willing to lower your asking amount to X. I'd try to make sure they get the impression that you are coming down from your initial expectations already, and be clear on if that is the lowest amount you would go or not. Also, I've voted to reopen your question as I think it's a good one for this site, and definitely not a duplicate of the linked questions. It needs 4 more votes though

Comment: Yes, that's a basic rule of negotiating. If you're selling, as for more than you want. If you're buying, bid lower than what you want to spend. Meet in the middle.

Comment: Is there a reason that this question has been edited almost 4 years after you asked it last time?  Is this question still relevant to you?

Comment: @PETE It still gets quite a lot of views and I happened to notice a spelling mistake. Thought I'd take the time to correct it as the Q seems still popular.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's easier to negotiate when you've decided what you want relative to the job market you're in and what is the lowest you'll settle. Usually, I base the lowest I'll settle on a particular job and consider other benefits, perks, length of commute, room for advancement, or some sort of personal satisfaction gained from working for this particular company.

You can get better at negotiating if you practice. Working out a strategy is part of it. Also, try to identify what is really important to the person doing the hiring. I took a lower offer once, but requested my evaluation occur in 3 months instead of the company standard 6 (There is a strong potential to give a raise at this time.). For some reason this would create a problem with HR, so they just gave me more money. Interesting because they stressed that the salary posted was firm. Everything is negotiable, so don't be afraid to play the game.

Answer (score 3):

You have to decide on two numbers: One, how much pay you would like to get. Two, what is the minimum that you would accept. If you would like to get 35k but you would consider 30k, then you ask for 35k.

Now it seems their offer was considerably lower, maybe 20k. There are three possibilities: One, they made a ridiculously low offer. Two, you are very much overestimating your value. Three, they are advertising a position and expect a beginner worth 20k, while you are much better and worth 30k-35k. In the second case, you've lost.

In the first case, you tell them that they won't find anyone for that money, because their offer is too low. In the third case, you need to convince them that they are better off paying 35k for someone worth 35k, then paying 20k for someone else who is worth 20k. If you can't convince them, you lost.

If you can convince them that a better offer is needed, then putting 35k into the room, with confidence, is a good start. You need to portray with confidence that you are worth 35k. (And we don't always get what we want or what we are worth, so the offer may be a bit less).

Don't be disappointed if their answer to 35k is "no" and they don't even consider negotiating. In that case you know you won't get your minimum of 30k, so nothing was lost. If they negotiate then you take what you can get as long as it is at least your minimum.

Comment: if you want 35 always start higher say 40-42

Comment: I would like all the money in the world.  I will accept considerably less.

Comment: @Neuromancer: I say what I want, with a thoroughly confident knowledge that I'm worth it, and I get it. "We don't have that money" -> well, tough for you. "We want to pay less than you're worth" -> well, tough for you as well. If I ask for more than I want I can't pull that off.

Comment: @gnasher729 so why are you not negotiating they may be will to pay more that you think your worth

Answer (score 1):

During negotiating, please do not forget total compensation. They may be stuck in a salary band, but PTO may be more open. Also, how does their benefits stack up against other companies in the area? Will this be a 9-5 job or weekend work? All this is to be considered.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote on this. It's not always about money.