# Trying to determine fair compensation across borders

Tags: salary, compensation, international

Before a third interview with a company, their HR representative asked what kind of compensation I would expect. If this company was in Canada where I live, I have a reasonable understanding of what kind of salary would be fair for my skills and could answer the question. However, this company is in the US, which I have no experience with.

What kind of best practices are involved in trying to determine compensation across borders, and also, **comparing** salaries across borders?

**Edit**: I would be moving to the US if I took this job.

Comment: Sorry. I can see how that wasn't clear. I would indeed be moving to the US. I'll edit the question.

Comment: So your question is less about figuring out the salary to ask for (see [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)) and more about how to determine what that salary equates to (cost of living, purchasing power, etc) in your current location, as a comparison?

Comment: That's a perfect description of the quandary @jcmeloni.

Comment: Some US specific info: http://www.salar.ly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One useful tool may be a cost of living calculator.  If you know how much you would need to accept a similar job in your own area, you can use a cost of living calculator to determine the approximate amount that would be equivalent in the target location.

A representative international calculator is [Expatistan](http://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living). It's a crowdsourced tool that can be used to compare the costs of basic services in many locations around the world, using current exchange rates.