# What is my job description? Since my own boss doesn't even know it

Tags: salary, title, job-description

So this is what i do

I work for a home health care staffing agency
I do the following bellow full time.

1. Office Manager
2. Payroll
3. Billing
4. Collections
5. I also go to court for lawsuits with our attorney
6. HR Part time

can you please help me as i really need to update my resume and i  need to know how much i should be getting paid because im only making $15 and i feel that im being underpaid

Comment: May I ask what you were initially hired to do, what your actual profession is, and what it is you want to do going forward?

Comment: I was hired to do billing & payroll Only & i'm trying to update my resume and i need to be accurate with my information

Comment: So you're an accountant? And if so, is that what you're interested in doing in a new workplace?

Comment: Most likely yeah , but what about the Hr and the office manger part where do i put that on my resume ?

Comment: How large is your company (# of employees)?

Comment: A general pointer: this site doesn't really give personalised resume advice so I'd suggest contacting a friend or contact with hiring experience to help you review and edit it. You can also ask for more personal help in our [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) but you need 20 reputation points on the site to join it. If you want to join chat ping me back (by using @Lilienthal in a comment) and I'll ask a moderator to give you access.

Comment: about 60 staff such as RN,OT,PT that work out in the field, but obviously come in to our office for paperwork they see home care patients and we staff them

Comment: Couldn't you just say "Office Manager/HR" and describe the other activities as duties of the role.

Comment: Operations manager to some extent fits the bill.

Comment: see also: [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you are severely underpaid. However, you also suffer from having your fingers in too many pies.

Anyone looking at that list is going to think: **Jack-of-all-trades, master of none.**

The fact is that in any decently organized business a different person would probably cover each of those responsibilities. Most people will think that the only way a single person can handle all of it is if at least ***some*** of those tasks are being blown out of proportion.

In your resume you have to take care to bring out the fact that you were trusted to perform all those tasks while not making it sound unrealistic that you did so.

> **My Workplace (20XX - Present)** 
>   ***My Job Title***
>   - Hired as Payroll Administrator, and successfully performed this function for the duration of my employment (a sub-list about this part of your responsibilities, etc.)
>    - Assigned additional responsibilities as Office Manager (indent sub-list of responsibilities)
>    - Trusted as representative in a court of law alongside our attorney
>    - Occasionally tackled HR responsibilities by performing he following:(indent sub-list of responsibilities)

Obviously this is a very crude version of what your resume might include.

However, before you send your resume out I would seriously think about the sort of job you want to pursue in the future and ***include more/less information about the aspects of your job that are relevant to getting the position you're applying for.***

If you simply list everything you either risk coming across as over-qualified, or projecting the image that you didn't actually do much in the way of accounting at that company you're currently with (since you had so many other things on your plate).

Comment: thank you very much, I truly appreciate that you took the time to help me out and i truly got my answers, I will admit that yes it is alot to do but i Multitask all those departments and its very stressful as the same time but i try my best as i truly need this job but lately i've been feeling sad and overworked and not appreciated it  , that's why i took the time to do my research and look for something better but know what to put on my resume! thank you again very much

Comment: In very small business it's not uncommon for one person to take on all these administrative duties. I think the typical term or title is "[office administrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_administration)". Your advice is spot on though. It's especially important for the OP to tailor his resume to the type of position he's applying for.

Comment: @workinggirl89 - glad to be of service. Hope you get a better job lined up!

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with Office manager
I would go with a hierarchy and list a primary duty
It shows structure and organization

I don't think you need to discuss how other responsibilities came to be

I don't see being spread too thin as a problem.  Those are all good skills and demonstrate an employee that is willing to adapt.  An office manager where they need those type of skills is a good fit.  Getting more than $15 / hr is not a problem.  Those skills are easily worth twice that.

Job history mm/yy to present Company X - Title: Office Manager

- Accounting (primary duty)

  - Payroll
    ...
  - Billing
    ...
  - Collections
    ...
- Legal Assistant

  - Prepare for litigation
    ...
  - Assist counsel at trial
    ...
- HR

  - Job posting
    ...