# Should I point out that I'm a woman when negotiating starting salary?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, salary, hiring-process, gender

The pay gap between men and women has been in the news lately so I'm wondering if it would be an appropriate strategy to use this when negotiating a starting salary at a new company as a Senior Software Engineer.

**Them**: "What salary range are you looking for"?

**Me**: "I'm sure you will provide an appropriate offer given my qualifications and experience..."

Do I finish this sentence by subtly implying that they shouldn't pay me less than men in the same position?

Options:

- given the current focus on gender pay equity.
- that would not come under scrutiny if a gender gap analysis was done on your payroll.
- that is in line with male colleagues.
- ...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or arguments about the severity of wage gaps; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41269/discussion-on-question-by-cili-should-i-point-out-that-im-a-woman-when-negotiat).

Comment: My somewhat irreverent take on it: If the person you're talking with can't tell you're a woman, then they won't pay you less for being a woman.  And if they can, then they already know you're a woman, so what good would it do to point that out?

Comment: I am shocked that you are even considering the *...that would not come under scrutiny if a gender gap analysis was done on your payroll.* part.

Comment: Is it a good idea to passive-aggressively accuse a potential employer of sexism/gender-discriminatory practices? It's mind-boggling and sad that this question was even asked, let alone that that 89 people here considered this worthy of an upvote.

Comment: Surely they already know you're a woman since they interviewed you -- pointing that fact out in a passive-aggressive way of saying "And don't cheat me out of salary because I'm a woman!" is not going to make the negotiations go any better.

Comment: @HopelessN00b this isn't meta; an upvote doesn't mean "I agree with the idea", it means "this is a good question for the site".

Comment: @AakashM since this question was stuck in HNQ list for quite a while, upvote does only mean that a random (typically inexperienced but [armed with association bonus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238420/165773)) site visitor [found it entertaining](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220099/165773)

Comment: @AakashM Yes, and it's sad that 93 people think a question about accusing an employer of being sexist is a good question for this site.  That's not a good question for **any** site, it's a clip on some *World's Worst Interviews* "reality" TV show.

Comment: @HopelessN00b "should I go ahead with this superficially-attractive-but-as-it-turns-out-terrible plan" *is* a good site question if it's something that might well occur to a large number of people who get the 'superficially attractive' part but fail to realise the 'terrible' part. SE is about education, after all.

Comment: @AakashM Accusing an interviewer of being sexist is superficially attractive?  Alright, then... like I said "*World's Worst Interviews* 'reality' TV show."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)

Comment: You are making an assumption about a specific case based on a general trend. I would rather not make an assumption that your salary would be discounted due to gender (and not some other reason), unless you have evidence that in this specific case it actually is/was. Also rather than turning it back on them to provide an "appropriate offer", why not actually answer the question and put a figure down that you believe would be fair based on market and your qualifications?

Comment: `I'm sure you will provide an appropriate offer given my qualifications and experience...` - No. No. NO. Absolutely not. "The salary I'm looking for is $X". And X needs to be in a range expected for the job you're going to be doing and the skills you're bringing. It shouldn't be rated against your previous salary or what you think your current company would pay you to do it. Negotiate against the value you bring. Your gender doesn't matter even in the least. People will argue that this may matter depending on locale, and I don't care about that. Respect yourself.

Answer (score 313, accepted):

Ok, as a woman who works in the IT industry and has worked as a Senior Software Engineer for many years, my answer is simply **Don't bring gender into the equation!**

I know what I am prepared to work for.  I know what market rate is for someone of my qualifications and experience.  There aren't two market rates, one for men and one for women.  *Negotiate for the salary that fits your expectations, qualifications and experience*.

Honestly, as a new person coming in to a new organisation, you probably have a better chance at hitting market rate, rather than someone going up the ranks within an organisation.  The differential at that point is normally because of promotions or lack thereof.

So all I can suggest is to educate yourself on what is the appropriate market rate for your experience, and, decide what you are prepared to work for, and go from there.

From your comment on an earlier answer:

> I'm a great software engineer but a lousy negotiator. I'm looking for an easy way to get fair pay

The most important thing to remember in any negotiation is *don't sell yourself short*.  There is no easy way around that.  I'm not the best negotiator myself, but I know what is fair and what I'm prepared to work for.  If that isn't met, then move on.

Comment: Following up on this, men are usually lousy negotiators too.  Self-belief is not a gender-specific thing.  The so-called "alpha males" swaggering in are usually outliers; and as an engineer I am *less* likely to give a job to them because they're usually not great team players.  I'd rather see someone say "I can do this job because look at all the similar work I've already done", rather than "I can do this job because I IS AWESOME, BRO!!!!"  (Thank you, we'll be in touch.  Next...)

Comment: Agreed. I (a woman) was going to say the same thing, so I'm glad I read the responses first. :)  Like you and Joe Strazzere have said throughout: know what YOU want, negotiate for THAT. Again and again and again.

Comment: "There aren't two market rates, one for men and one for women." should probably be changed to "There shouldn't be two market rates..." This may depend on which part of the world the person asking the question is working in. Unfortunately, not everyone lives in enlightened societies.

Comment: Learning some basic negotiation skills is a relatively small investment with large returns. It's unfortunate, but much of your career-long income is determined by a few short interactions usually separated by a multiple years. It's stupid and it's unfair, but that's reality. You don't have to be a top negotiator, you just have to have basic negotiating competence.

Answer (score 271):

**This is likely to cause offense.**  Such a statement would imply (without evidence) that the people you are negotiating with are likely to discriminate against you because you are a woman.  Suggesting that the people who are about to employ you are probably sexist is not a good way to start off in a new position.

**The idea that a significant part of the gender pay gap is caused by direct discrimination is controversial**.  According to the most thorough studies of the issue, most of the pay gap is explained by factors like different career choices, education, and experience.  The remaining portion of the gap may be due to discrimination, or other factors such as women being less likely to negotiate for higher salaries.  [Wikipedia summarizes the evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_pay_gap).

Most studies do conclude that there is some discrimination involved, but find that the largest part of the gap is due to other, measurable factors.  Typically, there aren't good ways to measure discrimination directly, so studies tend to infer that the portion of the salary gap not explained by any measurable factors is caused by discrimination.  While this may be reasonable, it is a judgement call, as there may be other unmeasurable factors that explain the gap.  [Here is more good information from Skeptics Stack Exchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/5178/11522).

It is not clear, based on the evidence, that individual employers discriminating based on gender for salaries is actually a meaningful contributor to the gender gap.  Even those who highlight the pay gap as a big problem often focus on arguments like "society values jobs women do less" or "women are socialized to go into lower paying fields" more than direct discrimination.

Even if you disagree and believe direct discrimination is widespread, there is still no evidence that your particular employer discriminates.

**Ultimately, the best option (whether discrimination exists or not) is to negotiate for pay that is in line with your qualifications, skills, and experience.**

There are lots of other questions on this site about how to negotiate salaries, so I'm not going to repeat advice about that here.

*Update: thanks, commenters, for the feedback.  I remain convinced about the main points I have made, but I realize that not everyone agrees.  I have added more discussion and the other reference suggested, and I hope it is a fair treatment of the evidence (whatever your conclusions may be).*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41283/discussion-on-answer-by-dan1111-should-i-point-out-that-im-a-woman-when-negotia).

Comment: This answer contains a lot of discussion on the existence of the 'gender gap', none of which is relevant to the question. (That's a comment on the answer, by the way, not a discussion of the subject).

Comment: @DJClayworth I disagree regarding it being irrelevant. Addressing flawed assumptions in a question is not irrelevant.

Answer (score 46):

No, don't point out that you are a woman.

You don't want to be paid in line with your male colleagues. You want to be paid in line with your qualifications. (And your skill at negotiating.)

If your male colleagues are less qualified than you are, and/or less adept at negotiating, you want to be paid more. If your male colleagues are more qualified, yes, in principle you want to have a matching salary, but then you are overpaid, and that could be a problem down the road - better to accept a lower salary and work on your qualification.

As [deviantfan notes](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/69858/should-i-point-out-that-im-a-woman-when-negotiating-starting-salary#comment192981_69858), asking for special treatment based on your gender can paint you as a high-maintenance employee, and not only salary-wise, but also management-attention-wise. Not good. Plus, you *don't* want something like this ever to become public knowledge among your peers. With professional HR, it won't ever come out, but if anyone ever mentions "that software engineer who got a higher starting salary because she's a woman", you will *not* be liked by your colleagues - neither men nor women.

Focus on your skills and qualifications, and negotiate well.

Comment: I'm a great software engineer but a lousy negotiator.  I'm looking for an easy way to get fair pay.

Comment: @cili you will be paid fair. In SoftEng, gender doesn't matter, the table you did show us is a good example, if you compare with the level of experience, it is really fair for women. When people speak about gender equality, it is about other field of activity, like building, teaching, etc...

Comment: If you are a lousy negotiator, I'm afraid there *is* no easy way. Work on your negotiation skills. Yes, that is possible. Here is a question: do you want to be paid in line with a male colleague *who is also a lousy negotiator*, or with one who isn't? If the latter, the best way is to focus on your negotiation skills, not on your biology.

Comment: @cili: and do you know what fair pay is? Then just reply that you want to make that, and say no if they go lower.

Answer (score 10):

You want to be paid like your male colleagues. That's good! Now, you need to negotiate like them too. Set your expectations higher (men tend to ask for higher raises) than you would.

You don't need to point out you are a woman, you need to point out how much they should value you (by first pointing to what you have achieved/accomplished during your time with them). Then you need to set forward what **you** think is a fair compensation for all the presumably good work you do for them.

I also urge you to read over Jane S' answer. This part especially is super important: "*Negotiate for the salary that fits your expectations, qualifications and experience.*". You are not negotiating for womankind, you are negotiating for *yourself*.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain the downvote so I can improve my answer?

Comment: I’d add to the last sentence: If your expectations are too low, negotiate for something higher than your expectation. If you think you deserve only 70k, because your expectations are too low, negotiate for 80k. If you think you’re asking for more than you’re worth, you got it just right.

Answer (score 3):

There's absolutely no point in raising the issue. Unless you have a very unusual name, they already know you're female. So any offer they make will already be constrained by their attitudes.

Also whether or not the general job market is negative is also irrelevant. At the time you'll be just one candidate of several.

So caution would be my watchword.

Answer (score 2):

This was going to be a comment but takes too much space.

I don't know that the pay gap is actually real. I believe that it's either:

- A remnant. Women moving up the org chart and getting a standard % raise based on older substandard pay.
- Totally made by the women going into the negotiation and  *expecting* to get less and there for accepting less.

For all the companies that I have had a hand in the hiring process (which usually would be for IT/Dev positions) There is a chart, a table, or a budget that is the constraint. Usually presented as $x - $y against experience and skills. Something like

```
1 Years - 100 - 200
2 Years - 120 - 220
3 Years - 130 - 220
4 Years - 140 - 220
5 Years - 150 - 230
```

Never have I seen a chart, table or budget that split out women and men. However I have seen the following.

The expected negotiation is:

What do you want?

I want something in the range of 150.

-- Then I look at the chart and see of there in range. If there near the bottom I accept. If there near the top we continue.

I would like to offer you 100. Consider that and the other benefits.

I can't do 100, how about 125.

Ok, I can offer 125.

I have seen woman who seem to expect to get less, and thus take the 100 offer with no counter offer (I have guys do it too, but it seems women do it more, though I don't really know why).

If there is a pay gap, I feel (can't prove) that it exists in that fact, and not in any way (for most companies) a deliberate effort to pay women less.

**Because of that I would suggest that the downsides outweigh the single potential benefit** (scaring them into doing the right thing.)

You could be passed up because you're making gender a thing. To be honest, when hiring any women or anyone really, I keep an eye out for people who think they are going to be in the default position of being screwed over. These people tend to think that they're being picked on when asked to work late, or that extra weekend. The new guy (or gal in this case) always gets the crap work. It's not picking on, it's seniority. So I try to weed out applicants that feel like they're going to turn every "Can you work late?" into "Are you picking on me because I'm a woman?"

Comment: A friend of mine is a manager in a tech company. His experience is that in his department, if a woman says "I want $X," she is offered $X. If a man says "I want $X," the next higher manager above him and the HR person (both female) negotiate back and forth between them and ultimately wind up offering him $X + 25% (sometimes more). I'm sure they don't believe they are discriminating.

Comment: So, as a man If I say I want $400 then I would be offered $500?

Comment: Your math skills are pretty good :)

Comment: I can honestly say, i have never heard or seen that. I have always been instructed to, and seen "go for the lowest offer they accept in range" If someone asked for way lower then they were worth, we would re-evaluate them. For example 3 years experience and asks for $50. They would be looked at again. If they asked for 120 we would just bump them up to 130 regardless of gender. But every company is different.

Comment: It's probably not a usual way to do things. I don't think the women involved are aware they only do it when the hiree is male.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to comment. I would not suggest bringing up "The pay gap between men and women" as this is a myth at best. There are no reputable economists or statisticians that acknowledge a gender wage gape exists in North America (assuming this is where you are as it is not specified, and please research this before commenting).

Discussing known myths as reality may cause some worry with potential employers. I would not discuss this with them, nor would I make your gender a major point of discussion, as your gender encompasses approximately 50% of the population, it is generally irrelevant.

> Do I finish this sentence by subtly implying that they shouldn't pay
>   me less than men in the same position?

This is a very bad idea. Displaying clear passive-aggressive tendencies *in the interview* is not likely to help you in any way.

Although some of what I have said is in previous answers, no one has addressed the pay gap as a myth, which I feel is important for future negations and consideration.

Best of luck.

Comment: To the contrary, the pay gap is in fact real, and it is due in part to discrimination. This has been settled: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5159/is-the-gender-pay-gap-evidence-of-discrimination The question is to what degree does discrimination play a part.

Comment: @charginghawk In the tech field the gender pay gap is against men, not women. http://money.cnn.com/2016/04/12/pf/gender-pay-gap/ among many explains.

Comment: @Lan Did you read the article? "Overall, women hired for jobs in technology, sales and marking were offered salaries that were 3% less than what men were offered, but at some companies the gender pay gap was as high as 30%", "Men received higher salary offers for the same job title at the same company 69% of the time", "Take the job of software engineer. Women were offered 7% less on average at major corporations versus being paid 4% less at small start-ups".

Comment: @charginghawk, even according to the link you provided: The pay gap is real, is *largely* due to other factors than discrimination, and *may* be due in part to discrimination, and a thorough look at the evidence indicates that it is a *reasonable* assumption—but still an assumption, not proven—to attribute the remainder of the gap to gender discrimination.  This is a more precise summary of the link you cite than to call it "settled" that the pay gap is due in part to discrimination.

Comment: Remembering that the HR department is not only looking for the best people, but also trying to save money, so they will offer as little as they think they can get away with. They will also offer less money to foreigners, or any other non-majority group, it's not a judgement of worth, they are doing their job.

Comment: So the answer is not to settle for less than you think you are worth. I once got a fantastic job offer because I didn't really want the job - so I said if you offer me x I'll take it, otherwise it's not worth the trouble to me. Then of course they offered me x and I had to take it...

Comment: @ognockocaten You should read your own sources.  It is clear that they are aggregating across the sexes and not across the job roles.  Their 12% difference is attributed to women not taking management positions.  The pay for the positions they do take is roughly equivalent.  So it's a mistake to call it a "pay gap" and more accurate to call it a "promotion gap".  If you get the job, odds are you will be paid roughly equally.

Comment: @Edwin Buck Sure, promotion gap, fine. Now, do you know why this question is getting necro’d after 4 years? Because a couple of people have kicked off notifications on it all of a sudden. Is it linked to from somewhere or something?

Comment: @ognockocaten I have no idea, but I find that StackOverflows "put it at the top if it gets any activity" sort of keeps a necro alive for a little while.  But there have been many reports of measurement bias in comparing wages across sex.  Those that benefit by having a cause often misreport that they aren't comparing within the job categories.  Yes, it's a problem that women have less desirable jobs, but the "wage gap" biases toward "raises for women" and that's not really the problem, it's more "equal positions for women" that needs work.

Answer (score 0):

What you are in effect asking is if there is a reasonable, low-risk way to deal with systemic gender discrimination risk.

Sorry, probably not.

There are no easy ways around systemic discrimination.

Stating you are aware of the problem doesn't help.  Asking them to be aware of the problem doesn't help.

You can look to find organizations which publically state they are aware of the issue and work to combat it.  Asking about this during an interview is high risk, as the reaction of people in power to being asked about "do you oppress?" is usually very negative.  You can see lots of evidence about this in this very Q&A, where people talk about being offended by the question, or treat someone who believes this is the case as someone not to hire.

The upside of asking is that you will pre-filter out the workplaces where the attitude is "there is no problem".  The downside is you pre-filter.  As a prospective employee, there is a large power imbalance, and often you need the job more than they need to employ you specifically.  Sometimes this isn't the case, and they need you more than the opposite: but modern business practices basically revolves around eliminating that possibility as much as possible.

If there was an easy way around systemic discrimination, the problem would already be solved.

So, rather than talk about it in the interview (or before!), examine the public statements of the company around the gender pay gap.  There are employers explicitly working to eliminate it, that study their own pay gap problems and publish their successes and failures pubically.  Seek out such employers.  Find employers that use objective, transparent criteria (almost anything will do!) to determine salaries to avoid the negotiation trap.

There are companies who will probably respond enthusiastically to being asked about their gender pay gap policies, such as [McMaster University](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2015/04/30/mcmaster-u-addresses-gender-pay-gap-3500-raises-female-faculty-members).  There are many, many others which will respond with deciding not to hire you, or flagging you as a troublemaker.

So, only ask a question like "what policies do you have to address gender pay gaps" or the like if you are planning to walk away if they don't give the answer you want.

This can be a valid option, and it does send a message (that their lack of gender pay gap policies can cost them hires).  But it sends a message at a cost, and with the power imbalance involved in interview and employment, odds are they aren't listening too hard to you.

Comment: I wanted to upvote but the last paragraph is pretty much the same mistake OP tried to make in the first place - that is asking "do you oppress?". Rewording the question changes nothing.

Comment: I don't think asking in general about policies to support the equality of women in the workplace would likely be offensive.  The problem with bringing up the pay gap during salary negotiations is that you appear to be implying something about the specific people you are negotiating with.  Asking about a general company policy to address a systemic problem does not have the same implications.

Comment: I am sure the company where I work has no policy whatsoever to address "gender pay gaps", but pays people according to what they are worth, as they should do. A good company wouldn't need a policy. On the other hand, asking the question alone is an indication of trouble.

Comment: @dan1111 This very Q&A implies you are wrong.  There are large number of people who respond very negatively to even being asked about this.  Look at gnasher *right under you*, where merely asking about such a policy is "an indication of trouble".

Comment: @Agent_L The last paragraph simply states "if you ask this question, and they aren't on-board, you should be committed to walking away".  People who think there is no need to address gender pay gaps will be offended and/or oppress *harder* (you are a "troublemaker") if you bring it up.  Thus only bring it up if you are willing to walk away if they don't respond enthusiastically.  There are companies that will respond enthusiastically: See [McMaster University](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2015/04/30/mcmaster-u-addresses-gender-pay-gap-3500-raises-female-faculty-members).

Comment: @Yakk It was added after my comment. I meant the penultimate paragraph.

Comment: @Agent_L Yes, I meant the same paragraph (I edited in the last paragraph instead of only leaving it in a comment).  The last paragraph just explains why it may be a valid option (when you are basically willing to walk away from the job if they don't answer the way you want).  This is a high-cost choice, but it doesn't mean it is never a good one.

Comment: @Yakk McMaster is exploiting the drama for their own benefit. If a policy is there, it will be advertised. That's the very point of having it. To determine if it's ok to ask, let's replace "female pay gap" with "insert religion-name-here values". There are many companies with religious values written into their mission, but if you ask for them where there are none you'll get labeled as a fundamentalist. And of course the biggest point is that having religious values has nothing to do with a company being good or evil one.

Comment: @agent_l I think you misunderstand what is at issue here.  This question is not about "does the gender pay gap exist", despite the large number of people talking about how it does not.  It is about asking about the company policy about it.  If you want to talk about its existence, please do so in a forum about that question.

Comment: @Yakk I never questioned the existence of the gender pay gap. I merely said that **policies** on it exist for PR reasons. And asking for a policy that's not there boils down to same old "do you oppress".

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not the best answer but let me bring this idea forward.

Depending on location (this is relevant).  Female Software employees are scarce, most people will find that having a mixed set of persona's in a team will be more productive and different solutions will be proposed and implemented.

That being said, they might even consider adding a female dev to their team more valueable instead of thinking you should get paid less. Especially in the IT field I don't believe people will handle this way towards you.

What I do see here is that you're basically giving them the choice on rewarding you for your expertise, if you don't come forward with a target wage they will aim below this. This is a thing I've seen in other answers (Like the top voted) that women tend to not ask for a raise or a better starting salary. If you do you will easily get better options.

I'm just a Medior in my country after half a year of being a Junior at my first job here, when I would not have asked for a certain amount I would have earned about 10% less than when I did (their offer was way lower).

That said, instead of bringing up I'm a woman which to me would be an insult as recruiter since it would imply I am indeed discriminating. That being said, if I as recruiter would think you're not worth as much as any other I would simply not offer you more or hire you. If you'd bring up the I am a woman factor I would reject you fully, to most people it's irrelevant it's about your expertise.

I would bring forward an idea of what I'd think be fair (and top it off a little so they can also lower it slightly and still make me happy).

I hope this gives some insights in your issue, as for female developers our company's lead dev is one and I'm totally happy with this.

Answer (score 0):

Idealistically, you should approach such negotiations without any regard to gender, for which the plethora of other advice holds true. However, there is an observed historical issue within the tech industry with regards to women and I can understand wanting to do something to address that.

During an interview during salary discussion is not the time to address it. Depending on where you're interviewing, many western countries have a bunch of anti-discrimination laws that prohibit factors like gender, age, marital status, etc. being of consequence in the hiring process. While some of these are harder to hide than others, it does put limits on the appropriateness of discussing them or calling them to attention during the interview. Attempting to use it as a negotiation tactic amplifies the inappropriateness of this and would not be considered professional.

However, earlier in the interview you can approach this subject indirectly by discussing gender equality in the workplace and what measures they have in place to ensure this. A number of companies are quite proactive in their diversity efforts and a good interviewer would welcome the opportunity to sell the position on these features, whereas others should at least confirm that they adhere to minimum standards mandated by local law. Depending on how they answer this, this may give you more confidence that when you do engage in salary negotiation, it will be on a level playing field.

Answer (score 0):

Women are underpaid because: 1. They are apparently less good at blowing their own trumpet in an interview, which makes them appear less qualified when they are not. 2. They request less money and accept lower offers.

At least the second part you can overcome reasonably easily: 1. Read up how much the gender gap is, less pay for the same work (not for the same job, but for the same work). 2. Decide what pay range would suit you (lower end = where you might consider taking the job but will first try hard to get something better, high end = where you sign right there and then). 3. Add the gender gap to your range.

When you think you are asking for too much money, then you are about in the right range.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I'll play woman's advocate here. Many of the other answers are based on the assumption that you've got the weaker hand in negotiations, and you shouldn't risk the hiring company's ire by asking a potentially offensive question. However, you are a software engineer and this is an industry with negative employment. So, I think it's altogether feasible that you have the stronger hand in the negotiations.

In that situation, it might not necessarily be a mistake to pre-filter workplaces that don't take gender issues in the workplace seriously. If a company's answer to a question about the wage gap is anything less than "the wage gap is a serious issue and we're committed to closing it," than that could reasonably indicate other problems with the company.

Maybe they're outright a bunch of sexist jerks, maybe they're merely indifferent on issues that are important to you, maybe they're just naive. I don't have much confidence in any of the above having your back should gender-discriminatory workplace happenstance (of which there are many varieties) befall you.

So, if you have the time and resources to find a company that fits your values (and there are companies that are proudly committed to closing the wage gap), aren't you just taking reasonable steps to protect your self-interest? There's nothing wrong with prioritizing a supportive culture over any other measure of a company.

Comment: `you shouldn't risk [...] potentially offensive question` It's not offensive, potentially or otherwise. It's threatening. It's telling the recruiters _I'm likely to sue for discrimination on the assumption that you're discriminating_.

Comment: @rath That's a subjective interpretation. I'm not sure I'd like to be a female employee under your management if you hear "I'm going to get sued" whenever someone says "gender pay gap".

Comment: Good software engineers are indeed in high demand, but not high enough that they can get away with making not-so-veiled threats (or otherwise being a jerk) in an interview. A **large** part of what any company - yes, even software companies - are looking for in an interview is how well you work with others. Insinuating that the prospective employer is likely to discriminate against you and making threats to them literally the first time you meet them is not going to speak positively to your people skills.

Comment: A good female software engineer isn't in demand because she is female. It's because she is *good* at what she does. We aren't in the trophy collecting business here. Software engineering is about building real stuff.

Comment: @ArnabDatta I'm not saying a female engineer is in high demand because she's female. She's in high demand because she's an engineer, and she can leverage that to find a workplace that values equality and diversity, more so than if she were unskilled.

Comment: @reirab I disagree that it's a threat. A company's culture and ethics is important, and I don't see a problem with vetting that, and I do think the high demand for her skills gives her leverage enough to do so. I think it's interesting that so many people are "threatened" by her discussion of the wage gap. The truth is, while you think she's seeking preferential treatment, it's men who are currently receiving preferential treatment, with wages, promotions, even at the co-sci ed level. There is a threat to men in facing increased competition, but it's due to fairer competition at men's expense.

Comment: @charginghawk Culture and ethics are indeed very important. And people who see themselves as perpetual victims and insinuate that people they've never even met before are likely to practice illegal discrimination against them aren't the kind of people who make a positive company culture. As far as it being a threat, I suggest you read the question again. There is no way to interpret "that would not come under scrutiny if a gender gap analysis was done on your payroll" as anything other than a threat against the company. It's clearly intended to be a threat.

Comment: If you can prove a gender pay gap due to discrimination in the organization I run, I deserve to get sued. My subjective interpretation of the OP's proposal is _I'm a woman, so give me more, or else_.

Comment: @rath i would phrase it as "i am not confident in my negotiation skill, but if that gets me a lower salary, then i am likely to pin it down to something illegal". While i get what you say, charginghawk, can't you see how someone might be threathened by that attitude? It reeks of "if i fail it's because i was discriminated against".

Comment: @Patrice FWIW, an answer has been selected and it isn't mine. I had no delusions about this being a popular answer. But the simple truth is, companies where there isn't a wage gap are in the minority, and it's very reasonable to want to work at one of those companies if you're a woman. Honestly, if someone suggested to me that I'm subject to an unfair and industry-wide pay cut, but I should pretend like it doesn't exist, well, I'd have choice words. And maybe I'd be wrong, maybe the system can't be changed, not for me, not today. And I guess it can't. Is that what people want to hear?

Comment: @charginghawk there are still ways to fight that without saying the word "gap". At the end of the day, i think people are tired both of those pointing to the issue saying "THERE IS NO ISSUE", and those pointing at the issue and using it for 100% of their problem. Anecdotal, but similar: i was a lifeguard at a pool and told a small kid to walk instead of running. His mom came and said i did that because he was black. Not saying it's the same thing 100%, but it can show how some people will use that issue and see everything THROUGH it. What if OP ends up getting a lower salary than her (cont.)

Comment: Male counterparts, but for reasons of negotiation in the salary, previous experience, or education? Jumping in the negotiation and highlighting a possible gap means that anyone hiring OP will be wary of ANYTHING concerning her salary. Is it okay?HELL NO. Is it a sad reality of our world? Yes. Should we be offended? Fuck yes! Does it change the fact that, at the end of the day, this is likely to hurt her more than anything? Sadly.... It doesn't

Comment: @rath, agreed, but more to the point: The current (US) legal system has for some reason (or no good reason) shifted the burden of proof onto the defendant to prove that a statistical disparity is *not* the result of discrimination, rather than requiring the plaintiff to prove the fact of discrimination.  Nor is any plaintiff ever required to prove that statistical disparity would not exist in the absence of discrimination.  (cont'd)

Comment: Thomas Sowell has written about this extensively: [one](http://capitalismmagazine.com/2004/07/the-grand-fallacy-equating-male-female-differences-in-salary-with-discrimination/) [two](http://www.eastbaytimes.com/ci_20334605/thomas-sowell-once-again-statistical-charade-rears-its) [three](http://townhall.com/columnists/thomassowell/2003/04/01/the_grand_fraud)

Comment: Kolsyra, I expect that a mostly or completely male team will be improved if you add a woman, assuming she fulfils the requirements. That’s not “trophy hunting”, which is actually badly sexist, just like your hint that women can’t “build real stuff”. It’s common sense.

Answer (score -2):

Well, no... First obviously, if you had a face to face interview, they should ideally have figured this one out. Second, if you feel the need to point out that you are a woman and "need equitable pay" kinda implies you are a jerk, or don't trust them to make a decision based on your qualifications/

Comment: This answer does not add anything new to the already posted answers. Please remember [not to repeat others](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/255/faq-proposal-back-it-up-and-dont-repeat-others).

Comment: I did not see any answers addressing a "face to face" interview.  Pointing this out in a setting like that is very unprofessional and would clearly put them on the "do not hire" list.