# How to determine the salary range for remote position?

Tags: salary, telecommute

I am actively looking for a new job, since my current project is coming to an end. And I am being offered and opportunity as Python Software Developer for Costa Rica, remote 100%. I have no clue as to what to ask for a salary, can someone please help me figure out how to determine a reasonable salary? It seems like a very good job opportunity and I don't want to screw this just because of asking too much or too little. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/896/2322 ?

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be worth whatever that job is worth in Costa Rica. But that may not be what they are willing to offer you. See also the many past questions about salary negotiation.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, have a look at payscale and other services, see the average for your position in Costa Rica, target a sum that can be negotiated and state that in your intended income. Now the important part, make the numbers if that will work for your lifestyle and your currency, if you end up even or below then this is a no-go, keep in mind that you're likely to pay taxes in both places (at least that's the way it works in our country) so you will need to pay for accounting services too.