# Is it appropriate to bring up currency devaluation during salary negotiations?

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

I am shifting my career into another module and while i have no professional experience in this field, i am pretty familiar with it as it share a lot of technical similarities with my current job. I have passed all interviews and received a job offer for 6k a month, i previously asked for 8k as my expected salary. My expectations were based on:

1- I have more skills and knowledge than a regular entry level even if i don't have proven professional experience in that field.

2- My country's currency got devalued by 48% so i feel that the salaries they offered last year are outdated and should be readjusted but i dont know how to bring this up?

The 6k offer is about the same salary they offered before devaluation and i know they are not based in egypt and their dealings is mainly in USD so while their sales wont be affected, our salaries are technically 50% less.

I want to know if it's proper to bring something up like devaluation and economy during negotiations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, [1878 questions with 'salary'](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+salary) and there is nothing in there you can use?

Comment: Most of these questions are generic salary negotiation questions, there is no scenario similar to mine, i've been researching for a bit and i cant find anything that relates to my current situation. 

Please either read the question thoroughly and understand the situation and offer help or just save your time and mine and just ignore it. 

There is 1878 questions with salaries on this website, 10000+ on other websites but there is a reason i took 5 minutes of my time to post this here.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)

Comment: You said 8k. Are you no longer happy with that? Are they pushing back on that number? It's not entirely clear what exactly you're trying to negotiate towards. Note that your country's currency getting devalued by 48% doesn't necessarily mean the company has any more money to spend (they might actually have significantly less money if they rely on imports).

Comment: I said i expect 8k, they offered 6k. I wanna get it up to 8k or maybe 7k even.

They are a vendor for a global software solutions company based in EU, they sell and provide support and in the revenue from these is not in local currency it's in US Dollars. So if anything they sell for USD(means it didn't get affected by devaluation) and pay salaries in local currencies which is worth less USD now.

My problem here is that i don't know if it's appropriate to bring this up or not?

Comment: @gnat did you just search for "salary", copied the first result and posted that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got offered the same salary they offered 1 year ago and i wanna
>   negotiate it without sounding too rude but at the same time i feel
>   that having no professional experience to show off in that field is
>   holding me back.

Clearly, you feel you are more valuable than someone with no experience, even though you have no specific professional experience in that field. Yet they have lumped you in with other inexperienced workers.

So you need to convince them that your actual experience translates into value for the company and should be rewarded via a better salary.

Explain about the technical similarities in the roles you have held and in the role you are seeking. Explain how that will enable you to come up to speed more quickly and perhaps reach a higher level than others. Explain why that is valuable to the company.

Also, talk about your country's currency issue if you feel that is something the company would normally deal with.

Remember that just because you may have more skills than the normal applicant doesn't mean the company cares or should care. It's not uncommon for a company to have a structure where they bring in entry-level workers, get some work out of them as they are trained, and have them around for a few years until they leave. In that scenario, there may be little benefit for them to pay more for someone with experience (since they never tried to hire someone with experience to begin with).

In the end, you need to decide what you need/want for a salary and be prepared to move on to other offers if this company doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: My main question was whether it is appropriate or not to bring up the country's economy issue, and i think you answered that.

Thank you very much for your advice :).

Comment: I tried making it more clear, sorry if it wasn't before.