# Can you use H1B LCA reported salaries as a base for salary negotiation?

Tags: salary, negotiation, visa

For context, I have been with my company for a few years and performance reviews are upcoming. One of the topics that come up is salary readjustment.

It was not too long ago that my company introduced a "leveling" system to give a sense of what level someone is and what are the requirements. After a lot of research, I am pretty confident that I am not being paid as much as what the industry would expect for my current position.

I recently came across how H1B Visa salaries are required to report the base salary to apply for Visa through an LCA. One such site that comes up is [this](http://h1bdata.info/index.php) which lets you find salaries for specific companies and I happened to be able to find my company and people who are applying for H1B Visa of my position and of my level are getting paid slightly more.

So my question is there something special regarding H1B visas or LCA reported salaries that might make them different or is it fair to say that these salaries should match up pretty closely with what I should expect my salary should be? I feel perhaps there may be a reason why H1B Visa holders may have slightly higher salaries than normal (most likely because if the company is willing to get a H1B Visa for them, they are great candidates) which is why I want to ask here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use anything you want, provided you don't break the law to get it.  This is public information, so its absolutely a good source.  Whether tis worth the effort vs just finding a new job and starting the negotiation there is an open question.

Comment: Thanks great advice. I was more wondering if there was something special regarding H1B Visa salaries that make them not a point for negotiation but if not, no worries.

Comment: Well, by law you're only supposed to hire an H1B if you can't find a qualified citizen.  In reality its totally ignored.