# I'm having trouble evaluating the salary offered for a new job

Tags: software-industry, salary, international, appraisal

As stated in the title, I have been interviewed for a job offer.

The job offer is for a .NET developer with Unity3D skills.
I am a .NET developer with 3 years of experience, but I am a beginner with Unity3D. The interviewer didn't seem to mind that.

I live in France and The company is based in Demark. The offer was at 32k DKK per month (384k DKK annually) for a position as Junior/Mid level developer.

Since I wasn't sure about salaries in Denmark, i went to sites like Payscale or Glassdoor to check for average salaries. I found out that the average is around 36k DKK (412k DKK) for someone of my level. The company doesn't seem to want to change their offer.

The problem i'm having is that there is a mismatch between my skills and the skills asked for. Is their offer actually good or is my understanding of the situation wrong?

Comment: You explained your experience and they offered you the job, so it seems they feel your skills are good enough for the position. "I am a beginner with Unity3D" - this does not somehow make a bad offer good. If you think it is acceptable, take the offer. If it's too low and they won't go higher, don't.

Comment: Evaluating the monetary value of some given skill, which is roughly what you appear to be asking, is unfortunately beyond the scope of this site. If possible, you might want to [edit] your question to make it applicable to others that know nothing about your job or the specific skills here, while also asking a more objectively-answerable question and having it be fundamentally different from [this linked post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for).

Comment: It's a remote job our do you needs to relocate?

Comment: @jean I will need to relocate, although it might be possible to do it remotely until I find a place to move in.

Comment: Brandin, Dukeling : I already went to sites like Glassdoor to evaluate my skills, what is confusing me is if I should count my lack of skills with Unity3D as the reason for lower salary, or if I should stand by the results of the evaluation and ask for a higher salary, especially since,  as I stated, the company doesn't seem to mind my lack of skills.

Comment: Looks like they are taking in account your lack of experience since they offered a little less than what you find on your research. If I was young and single I can go for the experience, do an amazing work and after when I got hardened (1 year?) by the experince ask for a raise

Comment: They offered you the job, which means you have the experience they need. Did they actually say "well, we were considering offering you X, but considering you don't have much experience with Unity3D, we're going to lower our offer."

Comment: The *average* salary on Glassdoor is 36k, and they are offering you 32k, which seems close enough to the average (assuming, of course, that the Glasdoor data is accurate, but let's not get into that now), so I am not sure I understand why you are concerned about that. If the offer is too low for your liking, then just reject the offer and get a better one elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is their offer actually good or is my understanding of the situation
>   wrong?

Their offer is only good if it's good *for you*.

If 32k is less than what you need to live on, then it cannot be good. It doesn't matter if it is less than a number gathered from anonymous posters on some website or more. It's about your needs, your wants, your ability to earn more elsewhere.

If the job gives you what you want in regard to opportunity, location, culture, and the salary is good enough for you, then it's a good enough offer to be worth considering.

Stop worrying about what others may or may not be making. Start worrying about you instead.

Comment: Hello, the problem i'm having is that, having never lived in Denmark before, it's hard to calculate from gross salary, what will be the net salary and what i'll need for daily necessities (food, water, electricity...). This is why the salary being under the average is worrying for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about that site. Very helpful