# advice around promotion during web development placement

Tags: salary, internship, promotion, developer, web

I live in England and started a 1-year web development industrial placement in September between 2nd and now 4th year of Comp Sci degree at a very large company with 5+ sites.

4 weeks in, the only other developer left the company and I have since been completing all development tasks across all the sites on my own. I have upheld all standard development tasks and made some big improvements to the sites which have been well received by the company.

Recently, I asked the company for a change in my job role as I'm listed as a junior web developer, and I'm currently paid minimum wage. I feel this is unfair for the duties I have, the pressure in case anything goes wrong, and the impact I have had with the work I have completed.

Does anyone with more experience have any advice for me, and given they agree to my proposal, what salary should I accept?

Comment: see also: [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/896/168)

Comment: Sounds like a discussion to have with your college/uni supervisor first as it's possible they have agreements in place with employers about salaries paid in return for opportunities given to placement students.

Comment: After 4 weeks the other developer left and I was left in charge of all development responsibilities. I have worked there for 4 months now

Comment: @LaconicDroid my uni supervisor agrees that I should not be in the position as the only developer, and if I remain so I am severely underpaid

Comment: @Michael - Thanks, that's useful information that could be worth adding to the question.

Comment: You said it's a "placement". Does that mean this is part of your formal university education and you cannot just go and get another job?

Comment: What do other students make, in their "placements"? Is it regulated by any body, university or government? Where I live, placements used to be unpaid, until minimum wage laws came, then they had to pay minimum wage. I'm asking because in a free market, paying minimum wage for a software developer is ridiculous, so there is probably something we don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Some people have pointed in the comments about how to ask for a Raise, I'm gonna put that to one side for a moment:

Let's talk about Job Title and position - since you've indicated you are a Junior Dev, but since 4 weeks into your position, you are the sole Dev.

If I look at your question, I understand that although you are the sole dev, you've been doing this for less than a year. With less than a year's experience (even factoring that you were the sole dev for this period), I'd struggle to upgrade your title to Dev or Senior Dev - as both of those titles come with an expectation of a certain amount (in time spent) of experience.

However, if you have been in this position for over a year, I think you can reasonably make the business case that for that year, you have acquitted yourself as the sole developer and have assumed the responsibilities of a more senior role.

This is the time when you ask the question "I would also like to discuss an increase in my compensation, to reflect these additional responsibilities"

Comment: For more clarity I have been making learning to make websites for over 3 years (2 years of uni) and the company have decided not to hire another dev

Comment: @MichaelF Uni experience doesn't count. All an Employer cares about is your business experience - and from that I gather you don't have 1 year of work experience as a Dev. Keep up the work, but realistically, you need to surpass that threshold before a change in job title.

Comment: I understand I am not a senior developer. But the company have entrusted me with all their development responsibilities and have no plans within the next 12 months to hire another developer. I feel with the range of knowledge I need to do the job as a full stack developer, plus the added pressure of being the only developer requires more compensation than minimum wage

Comment: Titles aside if a company was employing me as their sole developer I'd be asking for commensurate compensation.

Answer (score 0):

So get you Uni supervisor to move you to another post, that company should not be relying on you.

What happens in 8 months time when you go back to Uni? Will the company expect you to put your degree on hold? Work weekends and evenings?

Decide what you want to do then do it.