# What's the best way to put myself in position for a promotion

Tags: salary, promotion

Let me start by saying, I know working hard and doing good work is key. But let me explain my situation.

I'm a go-getter. I'm the type that is happy to take on new tasks, learn new duties, take risks when appropriate. I'm not a complainer...well, except for now :-).

I've had two jobs since college (8 years ago).One was an entry level position at a TV station as a sales assistant. I worked my tail off (not my words) and still to this day have sales people, my former boss, etc. come up to me and tell me that they have never been able to "replace" me. Before I left, I went to my boss and told her I wanted to be an account executive. She said, she would consider it. Three months later ...and after two new account execs had been hired, I took this as a hint and found another job. When I put in my notice, my boss told me she was going to move me to an AE at the end of the year. By this time, I had moved on and say "No thanks."

My current position, I'm a web developer and online marketer. I started out just as digital marketing, but learned to code because the company seriously lacked anyone with that skill. Additionally, when we needed another person to produce, shoot and edit video, I stepped up and learned on the fly. My supervisor tried to get me a raise, but HR said practically said "no."

I just put in my notice as I've been hired by a large credit union in my area. I want to start this job right. My goals are to be a leader, to move up in a company and actually make some $$.

That's why I'm here. How can I put myself in the best position to get a promotion should one come up? Have I been too eager/willing  in my previous positions that the employers don't see the value of giving me a promotion? I'm just at the point where I'm tired of being told what a good worker I am and how much value I bring to the table. Instead I want to be rewarded.

I appreciate your honest thoughts, even if it's "shut up and be grateful you have a job."

Thanks!

Comment: see also: [How can you evaluate your market value?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/550/how-can-you-evaluate-your-market-value)

Comment: Please do some reading on office politics. You need to have a network of people who want to work on your behalf.  You may also want to read this question:http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/why-is-it-important-to-gain-visibility-in-the-workplace

Answer (score 1):

Remember to hire and/or train your successor. Especially in a small group, it can be very difficult to promote someone who is doing an essential job unless there is someone else ready to carry on with it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I brought up training someone many times. I honestly didn't have a true vacation for the final 5 years because no one else knew/was willing to do my job while I was gone. I pushed for it and was always told "Yeah, we'll get to that."  That said, your feedback is helpful as I move into this new company, I'll make sure to make some adjustments and look for some way to hold my supervisor accountable without alienated him. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure that you are sticking around at any of your jobs long enough to give the management a chance to promote you. When you go angling, you have to give the fish a chance to probe your bait and enough time for the fish to make up its mind and go all out for the bait. At which point, you reel in the line. You keep reeling in the line at high speed without any fish at the other end. So you keep changing angling position and you keep reeling in an empty line because you are not giving the fish the time to get itself caught.

If you work for a large, established outfit, then don't expect to be promoted at the pace that you might be promoted if you were working at say a startup. Large outfits have clearly laid out procedures for promotion and these procedures may include time lines - time lines which might be too long for your taste. You have to understand your employer's culture and procedures and work with them. Otherwise, you're going to be doing a lot of lateral motion, where excessive lateral motion gets you tagged as a job hopper.

Comment: Based on OP's description he's had two jobs in the last 8 years. Is that "job hopping"??

Comment: @Brandin That depends upon whether the OP held these jobs continuously and it depends how long the OP worked as their jobs. As I said, move too much laterally and you get tagged as a job hopper.

Comment: I stayed at my first job a little over two years and left only after it became apparent I wasn't going to be moved to sales as I requested. My first job paid $10 an hour (commercial TV sucks) so I couldn't stay any longer. I stayed at my last position for almost 6 years. All that said, thanks for the advice. I've tried really hard to train people in my position, but my supervisors never let me move forward. In this new position, I'll make some changes though. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks  for filling in the blanks. I thought that there was something fishy about your narrative. You have put my doubts to rest. I am going to advise you to set goals when you start a new position, keep track on whether you are achieving your goals, revised your goals as is necessary, practicable and convenient - you want to take advantage of new opportunities as they arise - and move on when you decide that your progress is stalling. You shouldn't allowed yourself to get stuck in a rut for six years.

Comment: And my last piece of advice to you would be: never take a position with an employer if you can't give a good explanation to the employer after them why you chose to take up that position.